# CakePHP - error at redirectAction. array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-1.3

I use CakePHP 1.3

I'm trying to learn CakePHP and I was trying to redirect a controller. But I get a warning and I can't do redirecting to other action at all.

Here's the printed warning

```
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array [CORE/cake/libs/router.php, line 1078]
Warning (2): array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array [CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 158]
Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given [CORE/cake/dispatcher.php, line 204]
```

Here's my `login_controller.php` for sample of the controller which doing redirect to other action

```
<?php
    class LoginController extends AppController {
        var $uses = array();

        function index() {
            $result = 'empty';
            if(isset($this->data)) {
                $user = $this->data['user_txt'];
                $pass = md5($this->data['pass_txt']);

                $action = array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'login');
                $params = array('user'=>$user,'pass'=>$pass);

                $get_login = $this->requestAction($action,$params);

                if($get_login===true) {
                    $result = 'exist';
                }
            }
            $this->set('result', $result);
        }
    }
?>
```

And this is `user_controller.php` code

```
<?php
    class UsersController extends AppController {
        function index() {
        }

        function login() {
            $user = $this->request->params['user'];
            $pass = $this->request->params['pass'];
            $query = $this->User->find('all', array(
                    'conditions'    => array('id'=>$user,'password'=>$pass)
            ));
            $this->layout = false;
            if (isset($query) && !empty($query)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return compact($query);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Any help can do, thanks

Comment: You should use [Auth component](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Authentication.html) for your login. If you want to redirect you should use [redirect](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#redirect) method of your controller.

Comment: I know that part. Actually, I just want to "explore other path" and what it can do. But, when I try this scenario, I got stuck. So I ask a solution where is the fault in my code.